# Python validate arg is a list of specific object

Tags: python, list, class, types

I have a class that I created -

`class Class1`, and in other module I want to have function that gets as an argument a list of `Class1`(and makes sure that it is a list of that object). I want something like: `def my_function(class1: list<Class1>):`. However, this does not seem to work(interperter won't accept this). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is to use square brackets

```
from typing import Iterable, List

# Limited to just lists
def my_function(class1: List[Class1]):
    pass

# Will accept any type of iterable
def my_function(class1: Iterable[Class1]):
    pass
```